# FIrebase Firestore no detecta un documento recién agregado cuando hago una query

Tags: firebase, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

recien estoy aprendiendo a trabajar con firebase en esta ocasión me toco realizar una list de productos la cual en el primer render se trae solo los 10 primero, al final de la lista tengo un boton de cargar mas al darle al dicho botón este me trae los 10 documento siguientes, ahora bien si le doy a este botón y no hay mas documentos registrado muestro un mensaje de "NO HAY MAS PRODUCTOS DISPONIBLES", si llego a registrar un producto nuevo, y le doy a cargar mas, me sigue saliendo el mensaje de "NO HAY MAS PRODUCTOS DISPONIBLES", es como si no se registrara ese documento, por lo q tengo q recargar la pagina

codigo

el codigo para buscar:

```
 find(query) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        if (typeof query === 'undefined' && !query) {
          reject(new Error(queryNotDefinedMessage));
        }
        const queryIsAemptyObj = Object.keys(query).length === 0 && query.constructor === Object;
        const queryHasDefinedaWhereKey = query.fieldPath && query.opStr && query.value;

        if (queryIsAemptyObj) {
          // lo uso para traerme los 10 primeros
          this.collection
            .orderBy('title')
            .limit(10)
            .get()
            .then((response) => {
              this.start = response.docs[response.docs.length - 1];
              const data = this.getAllDocumentWithArray(response);
              resolve({
                data,
                empty: response.empty,
                size: response.size,
              });
            });
        } else if (query.loadMore) {
         // lo uso para traerme los 10 siguientes
          const queryHaslimit = query.limit || 10;
          const queryHasOrderBy = query.orderBy || 'title';
          this.collection
            .orderBy(queryHasOrderBy)
            .startAfter(this.start)
            .limit(queryHaslimit)
            .get()
            .then((response) => {
              console.log(response)
              if (!response.empty) {
                this.start = response.docs[response.docs.length - 1];
              }
              const data = this.getAllDocumentWithArray(response);
              resolve({
                data,
                empty: response.empty,
                size: response.size,
              });
            })
        }

      } catch (error) {
        reject(new Error(error));
      }
    });
  }
```

en el componente de react para el primer render tengo

```
  async fetchData() {
    try {
      const querySnapshot = await Products.find({});
      if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
        this.setState({
          data: querySnapshot.data,
          loading: false,
          initialLoading: false,
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          initialLoading: false,
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      this.setState({
        initialLoading: false,
      });
    }
  }
```

el metodo que uso para traer mas doc en el componente

```
  async handleInfiniteOnLoad() {
    try {
      // for get more doc need pass with  a key call loadMore
      this.setState({
        loading: true
      })
      const request = await Products.find({ loadMore: { orderBy: 'title' } });
      if (!request.empty) {
        this.setState(state => ({
          data: [...state.data, ...request.data],
          loading: false,
        }));
      } else {
        this.setState({
          message: 'No hay mas Productos Disponibles',
          loading: false
        })
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      this.setState({
        loading: false
      })
    }
  }
```

estas son las respuesta de firebase

cuando le doy a cargar mas por primera vez:

```
docs: Array(2)
empty: false
metadata: SnapshotMetadata {hasPendingWrites: false, fromCache: false}
query: (...)
size: (...)
_cachedChanges: null
_cachedChangesIncludeMetadataChanges: null
_firestore: Firestore {_queue: AsyncQueue, INTERNAL: {…}, _config: FirestoreConfig, _databaseId: DatabaseId, _dataConverter: UserDataConverter, …}
_originalQuery: Query {path: ResourcePath, collectionGroup: null, explicitOrderBy: Array(1), filters: Array(0), limit: 10, …}
_snapshot: ViewSnapshot {query: Query, docs: DocumentSet, oldDocs: DocumentSet, docChanges: Array(2), mutatedKeys: SortedSet, …}
__proto__: Object
```

despues de darle al boton de carga mas por segunda vez y haber a agregado otro doc

```
docs: Array(0)
empty: true
metadata: SnapshotMetadata {hasPendingWrites: false, fromCache: false}
query: (...)
size: (...)
_cachedChanges: null
_cachedChangesIncludeMetadataChanges: null
_firestore: Firestore {_queue: AsyncQueue, INTERNAL: {…}, _config: FirestoreConfig, _databaseId: DatabaseId, _dataConverter: UserDataConverter, …}
_originalQuery: Query {path: ResourcePath, collectionGroup: null, explicitOrderBy: Array(1), filters: Array(0), limit: 10, …}
_snapshot: ViewSnapshot {query: Query, docs: DocumentSet, oldDocs: DocumentSet, docChanges: Array(0), mutatedKeys: SortedSet, …}
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de encontrar la respues el problema esta aqui xd

```
 .orderBy('title')
```

al buscar por títulos si alguien agrega un producto que comience por A pero el ultimo registrado fue uno que comience por K no va encontrar este nuevo producto registrado Pero si registrar un nuevo producto con Z si lo encuentra